# Callback for after event, after add record in div

Tags: jquery

How can I call a function after the `after` event of jQuery successfully completed. Basically I want to add 10 records using after and then call another function.

Comment: you can use setTimeout()

Comment: i dont want to use setTimeout(), is any other way available.

Comment: I don't think there is another way

Comment: why do you don't want to use setTimeout

Comment: Because some time 10 records load faster and some times it slow, i want after complete data load call function.

Comment: then you need to share the function after which it has to be called.. you will beed to use s callback based solution

Comment: unless you share your code and explain what you are looking for there is nothing much to be done....

Comment: $( ".inner" ).after( data ); after this process complete i just want alert function, but alert calls before complete process.